# Spring 3 -- NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, javabeans

I have the following code in a custom tag.

```
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(pageContext
                        .getServletContext());
        Poll1DAO poll1DAO = (Poll1DAO) applicationContext.getBean("poll1DAO");

        // more processing follows, but the previous line has the error
}
```

Even though I have this in ghs1986-servlet.xml,

```
<bean id="poll1DAO" class="com.dao.Poll1DAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
</bean>
```

I get this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'poll1DAO' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1098)
    at com.tags.Poll1Tag.doTag(Poll1Tag.java:25)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.PollPage_jsp._jspx_meth_myTag1_005fpoll1_005f0(PollPage_jsp.java:602)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.PollPage_jsp._jspService(PollPage_jsp.java:195)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:781)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have a `<servlet-mapping>ghs1986</servlet-mapping>` in your `web.xml` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by autowiring my DAO class.

Answer (score 0):

Dou you have the file ghs1986-servlet.xml in classpath application?

Comment: I do have ghs1986-servlet.xml.  I'm not sure how to put it in the classpath, but I have it located in WEB-INF, and it was always accessed before I made the latest changes.